# Create parts of DSL as Quickfix from xtext grammar

Tags: dsl

I currently experimenting with DSLs with xtext. I want to implement a quick fix for the dsl I'm writing and I'm wondering, if there is a possibility in xtext or xtend hook (or something else) to generate a dsl fragment code from the DSL grammar and a given Ecore node.

For example

```
Model:
  entities+=Entity*;

Entity:
  'entity' name = ID  ('extends' superType=[Entity])? '{' 
        attributes += Attribute* 
  '}';
```

I validate that the Supertype may not exist, and I want to suggest a Quickfix (Ctrl+1) to create a new Entity. I know how to do the validation part and know where to implement the quickfix. But since the DSL is in development i do not want to write two code generators (one for creating DSL code, and the second for the code derived from the model) since the DSL is subject to change. I guess, that there could be a more general solution, since the grammar is known, because of the xtext grammar definition and the Ecore node I want to create, whose name I know from the validator. I also guess I am not the only one providing such a "feature" and thus I assume there is already a solution which i did not found yet.

My Question, is there a generic way in xtext/xtend building an ecore node or AST and serialize that AST back into xtext based DSL using the xtext grammar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is exactly that. You can provide your quickfix as a semantic modification to the EMF resource. Xtext's serialization mechanism will figure out how to convert your changes to the AST back to text.

Something along these lines should do the trick:

```
@Fix(MISSING_SUPERTYPE_ID)
public void fixupSupertype(final Issue issue, IssueResolutionAcceptor acceptor) {
    acceptor.accept(issue, "label", "description", null, new ISemanticModification() {
        @Override
        public void apply(EObject element, IModificationContext context) {
            Model model = (Model)element.eResource().getContents().get(0);
            Entity newEntity = MyDslFactory.eInstance().createEntity()
            model.getEntities().add(newEntity);
            ((Entity)element).setSuperType(newEntity);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you I will try that, but I assume, that you know what you are talking about ;-). I will accept your answer as soon as I verified that. Sorry for asking you such noob questions.